# Spring Boot 2.5.3 OAuth2 - Auth-Server and Webservice separate, after Login no endpont works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, okta

Following the example on https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/12/oauth2-spring-security-guide using the projects `Create an OAuth 2.0 Server` and `Build Your Client App` after the login, any endpoint accessed jumps to the root endpoint `localhost:8082`.

I don't use `Thymeleaf`, as my webservice returns data, not a page.

OAuth 2.0 Server project

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class Demo2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    public AuthorizationServerConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }    
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("abcd")
            .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("fDw7Mpkk5czHNuSRtmhGmAGL42CaxQB9"))
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true)
            .redirectUris("http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");;
    }
}


@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("john")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("doe"))
            .roles("USER");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }    
}

@RestController
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }    
}

application.properties
server.port=8090

pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>     
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>           
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I omit the context path, which the project originally uses.

Webservice project

```
@RestController
public class MyRESTController {

    @GetMapping("/securedPage")
    public String securedPage(Principal principal) {
        return "securedPage";
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) {
        return "index";
    }   
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}


application.properties
server.port=8082
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=UISESSION

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-id=abcd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-secret=fDw7Mpkk5czHNuSRtmhGmAGL42CaxQB9
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-name=Auth Server
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.provider=custom-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.scope=user_info
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.authorization-uri=http://localhost:8090/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.token-uri=http://localhost:8090/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.user-info-uri=http://localhost:8090/user/me
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.user-name-attribute=name

pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That works fine.

Now, when I use the OAuth 2.0 Server project with my webservice project, means I add the application properties from the demo webservice project into my `application.properties` I cannot access any other endpoints but the root endpoint `http://localhost:8082`.

I assume that the `WebSecurityConfig` in my webservice project is the reason for that. It looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    public static final String ROLE_MYUSER = "MYUSER";
    public static final String ROLE_MYADMIN = "MYADMIN";
    
    private MyUserProperties myUserProperties;

    public WebSecurityConfig(MyUserProperties myUserProperties) {
        // Load usernames and passwords from properties file
        this.myUserProperties = myUserProperties;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            //.httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            
                .antMatchers("/abc/**").hasRole(ROLE_MYUSER)
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/def1/{name}", "/def2/{name}").hasRole(ROLE_MYUSER)
                .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/def/{name}", "/def2/{name}").hasRole(ROLE_MYUSER)           
                .antMatchers("/ghi/**").hasRole(ROLE_MYUSER)
                //... and so on
            
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole(ROLE_MYADMIN)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();    
            //.csrf().disable()
            //.formLogin().disable();
    }    

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails myuser = User
            .withUsername(myUserProperties.getPortal().get("user"))
            .password("{noop}" + myUserProperties.getPortal().get("pass"))
            .roles(ROLE_MYUSER)
            .build();

        UserDetails myadmin = User
            .withUsername(myUserProperties.getAdmin().get("user"))
            .password("{noop}" + myUserProperties.getAdmin().get("pass"))
            .roles(ROLE_MYUSER, ROLE_MYADMIN)
            .build();

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

        userDetailsManager.createUser(myuser);
        userDetailsManager.createUser(myadmin);

        return userDetailsManager;
    }   
}
```

I had `Basic Auth` so far, I defined my two users with the two roles in a

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
```

Now switching to OAuth2 I removed in

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
```

the lines

```
.httpBasic()
.csrf().disable()
.formLogin().disable()
```

and added

```
.oauth2Login()
```

The behavior in the web browser is the following

```
http://localhost:8082
```

delivers correctly the data from that root endpoint, without any login.

Any other endpoint, like for example

```
http://localhost:8082/abc
```

first leads to the login page, where I enter the defined user `john / doe` from the OAuth 2.0 Server project, after that it doesn't show the expected data from the endpoint `http://localhost:8082/abc` , but jumps back to the root endpoint `http://localhost:8082`.

The first step I tried is to place

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
```

in the OAuth 2.0 Server project, into the class

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

but with that the login didn't work, it only accepted `john / doe`.

The next stept was to remove

```
@Bean
@Override
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
```

also from that class and define my two users in

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
```

where `john / doe` was defined.

The login with one of my users works now, but the wrong behavior still remains.
What else has to be altered, and where?

The access to the endpoints in my webservice project depends on the roles the user has.

My `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: first of all `@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableAuthorizationServer` are in `maintenance mode` which basically means that they are deprecated. The blog post you are referring to is over 2 years old, so there are a lot of faulty information there and has not been updated. Second of all its impossible to know anything without any logs.

Comment: Yes, your right, but the Spring Boot OAuth2 project is still updated, now 2.5.2. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/2.5.2/reference/html5/

Comment: There is not much logged. After the login or any endpoint request other lan localhost:8082 it jumps to my REST controller which serves the "/" path. What and how to log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here [OAuth2 Client Principal do not have GrantedAuthorities when authenticated by Other Custom Authorization Server (SpringBoot2 & OAuth2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56002447/oauth2-client-principal-do-not-have-grantedauthorities-when-authenticated-by-oth/56021022)

solved it.

```
CustomOAuth2User 
CustomOAuth2UserService 
CustomAuthoritiesExtractor
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to point something out on the OAuth 2.0 Server project and the Client project I rely on (https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/12/oauth2-spring-security-guide).

When defining a user `admin` with the role `ADMIN` in the OAuth 2.0 Server project

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin123"))
            .roles("ADMIN")            
            ;
    }
...  
}
```

and also modify in the Client project `WebSecurityConfig` to have a path `/helloworld` where access is only possible with the role `ADMIN`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/helloworld").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

and also modify the REST controller `MyRESTController` to serve that path

```
@GetMapping("/helloworld")
public String helloworld(Principal principal) {
    return "helloworld";
}
```

and with an additional path `/oauthinfo` which give the OAuth information

```
@GetMapping("/oauthinfo")
public String oauthUserInfo(
    @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
    @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User oauth2User) {
    return "User Name: " + oauth2User.getName() + "<br/>"
        + "User Authorities: " + oauth2User.getAuthorities() + "<br/>"
        + "Client Name: " + authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getClientName() + "<br/>"
        + this.prettyPrintAttributes(oauth2User.getAttributes());
}

private String prettyPrintAttributes(Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    String acc = "User Attributes: <br/><div >";
    for (String key : attributes.keySet()) {
        Object value = attributes.get(key);
        acc += "<div>" + key + ":&nbsp" + value.toString() + "</div>";
    }
    return acc + "</div>";
}
```

I observe the following:

Using the web browser to access the path `/securedPage` leads to the login, and with `admin / admin123` the login is successful and I get the `securedPage` text shown in the web browser.

Accessing then the path `/helloworld` leads to a

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Aug 03 09:50:50 CEST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
```

also the logged in user has the role `ADMIN` and the access to the path should have been allowed.

Access to the path `/oauthinfo` shows the follwoing:

```
User Name: admin
User Authorities: [ROLE_USER, SCOPE_user_info]
Client Name: Auth Server
User Attributes:
authorities: [{authority=ROLE_ADMIN}]
details: {remoteAddress=127.0.0.1, sessionId=null, tokenValue=W9T0llypwFCfgmXZDMyQTnMbOYc, tokenType=Bearer, decodedDetails=null}
authenticated: true
userAuthentication: {authorities=[{authority=ROLE_ADMIN}], details={remoteAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, sessionId=4DF4FBDFA08F0C8F19B347C0B17550FC}, authenticated=true, principal={password=null, username=admin, authorities=[{authority=ROLE_ADMIN}], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true}, credentials=null, name=admin}
oauth2Request: {clientId=abcd, scope=[user_info], requestParameters={code=wnYl7w, grant_type=authorization_code, scope=user_info, response_type=code, state=z0MyCHpWUVVeVgLIP6vuP4ELzETmN5sziM-gZxBKsY0=, redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/, client_id=abcd}, resourceIds=[], authorities=[], approved=true, refresh=false, redirectUri=http://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/, responseTypes=[code], extensions={}, grantType=authorization_code, refreshTokenRequest=null}
principal: {password=null, username=admin, authorities=[{authority=ROLE_ADMIN}], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true}
credentials: 
clientOnly: false
name: admin
```

And it looks like, that the role compared on the path restriction for `/helloworld` is not `ADMIN` (authority `ROLE_ADMIN`), but `USER` (authority `ROLE_USER`), which is given in the second line of the ouput:

```
User Authorities: [ROLE_USER, SCOPE_user_info]
```

If I would change that from `.hasRole("ADMIN")` to `.hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")`, it works only with `USER` and `ROLE_USER`.

I don't understand what the problem here is.
Is it right to define the users in the OAuth 2.0 Server project?

And overall the question is: Is this the right approach or even library to achive what I want do achive?

With `Basic Auth` my `WebSecurityConfig` is given, with some path restrictions depending on the roles the logged in user has.

Switching from `Basic Auth` to `OAuth2`, what has to be modified with respect to having the `Authorization Server` as a separate project?

The code from the okta-developer projects i rely on is available at https://github.com/oktadev/okta-spring-boot-authz-server-example

If the path restrictions with roles can be solved first in that simple `OAuth 2.0 Server` and `Spring Boot OAuth 2.0 Client` project, then my webservice project will work too, I believe.